# Problem exproting ALBERT model from huggingface to ONNX

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, onnx

I am trying to export [this](https://huggingface.co/ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2?context=My%20name%20is%20Sarah%20and%20I%20live%20in%20London&question=Where%20do%20I%20live%3F) huggingface model to ONNX format, but I am confused how to export the model so I can change the question and context when performing inference with the onnx model. My code:

```
#Test example running model from huggingface
import os
import torch
os.environ["HF_ENDPOINT"] = "https://huggingface.co"

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2")

model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2")

# Define the question and context
question = "Where do I live?"
context = "My name is Peter from Australia"

# Tokenize the input
inputs = tokenizer(question, context, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")

# Perform the question answering task
outputs = model(**inputs)
start_scores = outputs.start_logits
end_scores = outputs.end_logits
start_index = torch.argmax(start_scores)
end_index = torch.argmax(end_scores) + 1
answer_tokens = inputs["input_ids"][0][start_index:end_index]
answer = tokenizer.decode(answer_tokens)

# Print the answer
print(answer)

#Answer
australia
```

so I export to onnx via

```
import torch.onnx

# Define the input and output names for the ONNX model
input_names = ["input_ids", "attention_mask"]
output_names = ["start_scores", "end_scores"]

# Export the model to the ONNX format
torch.onnx.export(model,                                      # model to export
                  (inputs['input_ids'], inputs['attention_mask']), # input as tuple
                  "albert_qa.onnx",                            # output ONNX model name
                  input_names=input_names,                    # names for input tensor
                  output_names=output_names,                  # names for output tensor
                  opset_version=11)                            # ONNX opset version

print("Model saved in ONNX format.")
```

but when I go to try and load the model to perform inference, unless I keep the tensor size the same for the inputs (i.e. the same question and context) it throws an error:

```
#Load the ONNX model and perform inference

import onnxruntime
import numpy as np

# Load the ONNX model
ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("albert_qa.onnx")

# Define the question and context


# Tokenize the input
inputs = tokenizer(question, context, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask']

# Run inference on the ONNX model
ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: input_ids.cpu().numpy(),
              ort_session.get_inputs()[1].name: attention_mask.cpu().numpy()}
ort_outputs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)

# Extract the start and end scores from the outputs
start_scores = ort_outputs[0]
end_scores = ort_outputs[1]

# Find the start and end indices of the answer span
start_index = start_scores.argmax()
end_index = end_scores.argmax() + 1

# Get the answer tokens and decode them
answer_tokens = input_ids[0][start_index:end_index]
answer = tokenizer.decode(answer_tokens)

# Print the answer
print(answer)
```

the error being

```
InvalidArgument: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : Got invalid dimensions for input: attention_mask for the following indices
 index: 1 Got: 15 Expected: 26
 Please fix either the inputs or the model.
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to ensure that while exporting to onnx, the model can take variable lenght input, add this inside your torch.onnx.export()

```
dynamic_axes={"input_ids": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
                            "attention_mask": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
                            "start_logits": {0: "batch_size"},
                            "end_logits": {0: "batch_size"}}
             )
```